# How to add map into browser using OpenLayers 3 and GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am new to OpenLayers 3, no error is showing in console, but the map is not showing in browser.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>mymap</title>
    <script src='js/ol.js'></script>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ol.css'>
    <style>
        body
        {
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }   
        #map{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>    
    <script>
    function init(){
        map = new ol.Map({
            target:'map',
            renderer:'canvas',
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:900913',
                center: [8310801, 1739730.625],
                zoom:5,
                maxResolution: 3384.54638671875
            })
        });

        var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: "mymap",
            preload : Infinity,
            serverType : 'geoserver',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                params : {
                    'LAYERS' : 'mymap',
                    'TILED' : true  
                }
            })
        })
         map.addLayer(newLayer);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the height of the map-div to 100% you should use percentage for the parent Elements, too:

Just try to add this to your style-section:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

More info: http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Edit1: Just tested your javascript with my own WMS-Service and it works fine.
First of all you could add a baselayer to see if ol3 itself is working fine:

```
map.addLayer(
                             new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
      );
```

After that you could check your layer-name: is your layer really not bound to a workspace or did you forget to use the workspace-name like  "myworkspace:mylayer" in the "Layers"-section?
You could also just use one of the default Geoserver-Layer that you will find in the OpenLayers-Preview to see if the problem has something to do with your WMS-Service or not.